# is it possible to add 3 photos to this code?

Tags: javascript, html

for this task i have to get 3 photos and make a button to cycle through the photos new i need to make it so that i can use photos from my file 
.Every little helps :D

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<img id="light" src="Red.png">

<script>
var list= ['Green.png', 'Yellow.png', 'Red.png']; 
var i = 0;
function lightsCycle() {
    i = i + 1;
    i = i % list.length;
    var light = document.getElementById("light").src = list[i];
}
</script>

<button type = "button" onclick="lightsCycle()">Next Light</button>
</body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE**: I have modified my code to attempt one of the answers given here, but I am still having trouble:

```html
        <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    
    <img id="light" src="Red.png">
    
    <script>
    var list= ['https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/crystalproject/crystal_project_256x256/apps/daemons.png',
    'https://img.clipartfox.com/837fed127e3383c2a61cf08f76a65081_pics-for-stop-light-yellow-clipart-traffic-light-yellow_641-880.png', 
    'http://previews.123rf.com/images/blojfo/blojfo1003/blojfo100300021/6559248-Traffic-light-with-red-light-Stock-Photo.jpg']; 
    var i = 0;
    function lightsCycle() {
        
        i = (i < list.length - 1) ? ++i : 0;
        
        document.getElementById("light").src = list[i];
    }
    
    </script> 
    
    <img id="light" src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/crystalproject/crystal_project_256x256/apps/daemons.png">
    <button type = "button" onclick="lightsCycle()">Next Light</button>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Add 3 photos to what?

Comment: Are you getting a 404 error ?

Comment: no error i am not fully finished the code i just need to add 3 photos of game titiles in a ranking system if that makes sense so Green is best yellow is good and red is worst and they will have lights above them if that is possible

Comment: First off, you know that "Green.png" is index 0 right?  Arrays are zero based.   So I am thinking you don't want to increment "i" until after you change the photo.  Second, as Joeri asks, are you getting an error of any type?

Comment: no when i try to run the code it just displays the code.

Comment: infact it just displays a webpage with a BMW on it ahahah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your function, you are incrementing `i` and then immediately throwing that value away on the next line where you are setting `i` to the modulo of `i` and the length of your array. That line is not needed.

You also need to check to see if `i` is at the highest index number that the array supports and, if so, reset it to `0`.

Next, the line:

```
var light = document.getElementById("light").src = list[i];
```

unnecessarily declares a variable called `light` since you never use it anywhere.

Lastly, don't use HTML attributes to hook up event handlers (onclick, onmouseover, etc.) as they:

create spaghetti code (HTML and JavaScript mixed on the same line) that is difficult to read and maintain.
create globally scoped wrapper functions around your attribute's value that alter the `this` binding and can cause your function to not work correctly.
don't follow **[W3C standards for event handling](https://www.w3.org/TR/2013/WD-DOM-Level-3-Events-20131105/#methods-1)**.

```js
// Put the correct relative paths to your images back into the array. Here, I'm substituting 
// online images so that you can see the code working properly.
var list= ['https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/crystalproject/crystal_project_256x256/apps/daemons.png',
'https://img.clipartfox.com/837fed127e3383c2a61cf08f76a65081_pics-for-stop-light-yellow-clipart-traffic-light-yellow_641-880.png', 
'http://previews.123rf.com/images/blojfo/blojfo1003/blojfo100300021/6559248-Traffic-light-with-red-light-Stock-Photo.jpg']; 

var i = 0;

// Only scan the document one time to get a reference to the image element.
// It's a waste of resources to do it every time the button is clicked
var img = document.getElementById("light");
var btn = document.getElementById("btn")

// Don't use HTML attributes to hook up event handlers (onclick, onmouseover, etc.)
btn.addEventListener("click", lightsCycle);

function lightsCycle() {
    // If i is less than the max index, increment it, otherwise set it to zero
    i = (i < list.length - 1) ? ++i : 0;
    // Set the source of the image element to the next array value
    img.src = list[i];
}
```

```css
img { width:50px; }
```

```html
<img id="light" src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/crystalproject/crystal_project_256x256/apps/daemons.png">
<button type="button" id="btn">Next Light</button>
```

Comment: you see when you have typed in that web address is it possible to do that from the documents ?

Comment: @DMC Yes, but in this environment, we need to reference images that you can see. We can't access your images from here. Just replace the strings in the array with the correct relative paths to your image files.

Comment: when i try to implement what you have given me into my code i get taken to an new 1 homepage ?

Comment: @DMC You need to update your question to show the exact code that you have written. There is nothing here that would cause page navigation.

Comment: Ok i am sorry trying to update it now

Comment: @DMC Your code is not the same as mine. You have two `img` elements named `light` on the page, instead of just one. And, as you can see, even though it doesn't work correctly, it doesn't navigate you to a new page.

Comment: @DMC Also, (just FYI), you should have *updated* your question by adding the new code onto the end of it, instead of replacing the original code. That way, the question and it's comments and answers remain relevant.